# Why Markdown does not align image properly?

Tags: image, github, alignment, markdown, line-breaks

I am using below lines for getting aligned images in a row in Github markdown, but last image always breaks the line even though there are space.

#### Code

```
# Example Img alightment #
<img align="left" src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
<img align="center" src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
<img align="right" src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/dev/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
```

#### Output

[image]

**How can I align all three images in single row?**

Reference: https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/dev/architecture/example.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need them in one row without centering you can do the following (just place images without new lines or with the `<p>` tag):

```
<img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/> <img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/> <img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/dev/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
```

or

```
<p>
  <img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
  <img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/master/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
  <img src="https://github.com/hissain/CoronaTracker/blob/dev/architecture/Screenshots/Android/Screenshot_Registration.png" alt="Android Registration" width="200"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks ilua.lehchylin, though the root cause of the problem in my approach is not yet known to me.

Answer (score 0):

While working on my GitHub [ReadMe](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/AsteroidsInCompose/blob/master/README.md) file, I found out that to create extra spaces before, after, or in-between your text or image you can use the `&nbsp;` -  **Non-Breaking Space** -  extended HTML character.

For example, you can do something like this to add padding or margin to a set of 3 images in a row on a MarkDown file.

```
<p float="left">

<img width="200" height="400" src="https://github.com/TonnieDev/screenshot_1.png"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<img width="200" height="400" src="https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/screenshot_2.png"> &nbsp;&nbsp;   
<img width="200" height="400" src="https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/screenshot_3.png"> 
  
</p>
```

The *more spaces needed the more you need to duplicate* `&nbsp;` charactes.